# What to do about answers which are highly upvoted but don't technically answer the question?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer

So I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9732709/8718143) today. I saw that the [second most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24271455/8718143) on the question only referenced the accepted answer and added an extra piece of information, so I decided to edit the reference out as it didn't seem relevant (did not answer the question).

Afterwards, I went back to the question and realised that the answer was completely unrelated to the question, and only expands on it in a manner that is interesting but irrelevant to the question being asked. As the user originally noted in their post, it should have been a comment on the accepted answer.

That said, the post has 33 upvotes, so some people obviously liked it. It's really just a "hack", however, and I don't think it has a place as an answer to that question.

There's another answer of a similar nature on that page, but it has been downvoted a bunch, probably because it's incorrect.

What should be done about posts of this nature? Should they simply stick around, because of historical significance? Should they be edited into an actual answer? Perhaps they should be placed as comments on the actual answer?

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: I'm leaning towards "historical significance", but only because I think there are bigger fish to fry.

Comment: Fair enough @BoltClock. I figure it's worth sorting these things out, if only to sort out that we should do nothing.

Comment: Always a good idea. That's what meta is for. That said, let's see what others have to say.

Comment: If it's an attempt at answering I don't really see why anything needs to be done with it, except of course downvote it if you feel it's not a *good* attempt.

Comment: It has +36/-3 so apparently some people came across it and thought it was helpful, isn't that a good thing?

Comment: Except it's not really an attempt at answering @ivarni, it's an unrelated piece of information that is only an extra tidbit of information about the accepted answer. It has *literally nothing* to do with the original question that was asked.

Comment: @ivarni I won't dispute, however, that people might have found it useful. That's why I'm asking the question about it here.

Comment: Is that information readily available somewhere else with high visibility? I can't imagine that tidbit isn't contained in an answer that relates to the question somewhere else on Stack (I am too lazy to check for it myself atm, sorry :/). I'd say it changes things.

Comment: I come across content I find out of place all the time. So I do my moderation privileges (vote, flag) if applicable and move on. Just because I personally think so doesn't make it actually so, if it has 30 upvotes then I can only assume somewhere around 15 people voted up seriously and not just followed the voting herd. I'm probably still way too naive when it comes to that assumption, but you need to have some faith in your fellow Stackers.

Comment: @ivarni If it's a useful piece of information then there's no problem in the answerer asking a new question tailored to the answer, and then self answering that. That way the useful information is retained, and it correctly fits the QA format. Also with a well written question it'll be easier to find than the answer alone.

Answer (score 12):

While it may not directly answer the OP's question, it is still relevant information within the domain of that question. When a question has already been sufficiently answered, it's not uncommon for other users to tack on additional answers that offer expanded advice or alternatives that do not, by the strictest standards, directly answer the question but which many, many other users find helpful when they are still learning about the technology. Our bar for "not an answer" is actually [quite high](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/211627), because it's extremely difficult to clearly define what "counts" as an answer, so we err on the side of caution. The best way to judge this answer is on whether or not it's useful, and so far the voting history would suggest that it is useful to most people. I say leave it alone.

That said, if you think the advice is wrong or unhelpful, please feel free to downvote it.

Comment: I believe it is extremely important to look at answers with a broad mind. When you land on a question via a Google search, your problem is *related* but *different*. Of course, we don't want people to just throw everything and the kitchen sink on a single question, but additional advice, work around, slightly reformulated problems, etc... are all useful.